# Get data from request in template django

Tags: django, templates, request

I wonder is it a bad idea to get data from request session or is it better to parse the data into dict context and render it (Need to do it for each view)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's common practice to send what you need through the context in the view.

I feel like it gives you a little more security/certainty in what you're doing because you can keep your logic in the view where it should be rather than doing any checks in the template for things being in the request.

*edit*

The above is only true if you're looking to do something rarely. If you're regularly adding an element of the request to your templates you should indeed, as everybody else suggests, be writing context processors to make what you require available to all views.
Take a look at the docs; [TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS)

Also give this chapter of the django book a read as it'll be very helpful; [Chapter 9: Advanced Templates](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter09.html)

Specifically this section;

> **Guidelines for Writing Your Own Context Processors**
>
> Here are a few tips for rolling your own:
>
> - Make each context processor responsible for the smallest subset of functionality possible. It’s easy to use multiple processors, so you might as well split functionality into logical pieces for future reuse.
> - Keep in mind that any context processor in TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS will be **available in every template** powered by that settings file, so try to pick variable names that are unlikely to conflict with variable names your templates might be using independently. As variable names are case-sensitive, it’s not a bad idea to use all caps for variables that a processor provides.
> - It doesn’t matter where on the filesystem they live, as long as they’re on your Python path so you can point to them from the TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS setting. With that said, the convention is to save them in a file called context_processors.py within your app or project.

Comment: I disagree; as you could end up with a VERY large dict being passed which would just clutter up  your views; particularly if you need a value in many views.  When I find myself reusing a variable in multiple views, i usually build either a filter/tag or put it in a context-processor

Comment: @warath-coder yes, I disagree with myself now, given the talk of context processors. I was taking a simple answer thinking 1 or 2 views may need part of the request. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

you can add this to your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS if you are accessing the request object in templates frequently (like I do for URL get parameter processing).

`"django.core.context_processors.request",`

Comment: As of Django 1.8 and 1.9, it's `django.template.context_processors.request`, not `django.core.context_processors.request`, and it is set in the list  `TEMPLATES['OPTIONS']['context_processors']`, not `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`.

https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.9.x/django/template/context_processors.py

Answer (score 0):

Django gives you a way to put data into every template, it is called context processors.

http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/14/django-tips-template-context-processors/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/api/