# django filter for URL that consists of two variables

Tags: django, django-templates

In all code snippets I see basic pattern of how filter is applied to an URL. For example,

```
<img src="{{obj.url|filter}}" />
```

I wonder how can I use filter with URL that consists of two parts?

```
<img src="{{something}}{{obj.url}}" />
```

Note: filter should deal with the complete URL, not just the second part of it

**EDIT:**

Model:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    token = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    reference = models.ForeignKey(Reference)
```

View:

```
def index(request):
    foos = Foo.objects.filter(reference=value).all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'foos' : foos})
```

Template:

```
{% for foo in foos %}
    <img id="foo_{{foo.pk}}" src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{foo.token}}" />
{% endfor %}
```

As a matter of fact, I want to just apply easythumbnail URL filter to image URL, which has two parts.

Comment: If you're dealing with context variables why not pass what you want specifically through the context?

Comment: that's a good option indeed. thank you.

but in my case I have a collection of objects returned from a model and I iterate through that collection, which means that I would need to change each individual object in that collection.

Comment: Can you provide an example in an update to your question? Sounds like a method on the model might be what you want if you're doing this with objects.

Comment: @marksweb I don't have much experience with Django and feel reluctant embedding MEDIA_URL into model's internal data.

Comment: you don't need to store the `MEDIA_URL` but you can use media attributes to make sure of it. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wanting to do things with context variables like this then you should make what you require available in the context rather than trying to manipulate things in the template.

Either add variable from your view or create a context processor if you have variables that you require in lots of places, because through a context processor you can create variables that are always available.

Check out this answer I wrote recently on this; https://stackoverflow.com/a/27797061/1199464

*update following your comment*

There's nothing wrong with writing a method on your model to format a string or similar;

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    token = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    reference = models.ForeignKey(Reference)

    def get_url(self):
        url = u'{media_url}{path}'.format(
            media_url=settings.MEDIA_URL,
            path=self.token
        )
        return url
```

Template:

```
{% for foo in foos %}
    <img id="foo_{{ foo.pk }}" src="{{ foo.get_url }}" />
{% endfor %}
```

And on a sidenote if you're not too familiar with Django yet, you should use `MEDIA_URL` for user uploaded content and `STATIC_URL` for content that is yours. You can read more on these here; [How can I get the MEDIA_URL from within a Django template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323686/how-can-i-get-the-media-url-from-within-a-django-template)

Django docs; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#media-url

Comment: thank you! that's what fascinates me in Django/Python - flexibility and yet power! great!